# Picture Box doesn't change with location if statement and timer

Tags: c#

I'm working on a game in Visual Studio, and whenever the enemy picture box reaches the player box, it's supposed to change the player's image to a death gif, start the timer, and when the timer ends, reset the enemies, stop their movement, and hide the player and enemies. However, when the enemy box reaches the player box, it does everything correctly except playing the death gif. Here's what I have in code:

```
        private void SpriteDeath()
    {
        if (enemyNPC1.Location.X > 280)
        {
            spritePC.Image = _KnightDeath;
            DeathTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
            DeathTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(DeathTimer_Tick);
    }
```

And then at the Death Timer:

```
        private void DeathTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DeathTimer.Start();
        DeathTimer.Stop();
        spritePC.Hide();
        enemyNPC1.Hide();
        enemyNPC1.Location = new Point(12, 445);
        ZombieTimer1.Enabled = false;
        enemyNPC2.Hide();
        enemyNPC3.Hide();
        enemyNPC4.Hide();
        enemyNPC5.Hide();
        enemyNPC6.Hide();
    }
```

The other enemy NPCs are intentionally left without the extra code until I figure out the problem. Can someone help me out?

Comment: try `spritePC.Refresh();` right after `spritePC.Image = _KnightDeath;`

Comment: also, do you unsubscribe from this `DeathTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(DeathTimer_Tick); ?`

Comment: I don't believe so. I'll try the refresh

Comment: I added the spritePC.Refresh(); and now it only plays the first two frames of the gif, but for some reason the gif plays super slow, so the two frames are shown in the span of a two seconds.

Comment: What do you mean when you say unsubscribe from DeathTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(DeathTimer_Tick); ?

Comment: well, you subscribe to `DeathTimer.Tick` but do you also unsubscribe from it? like `DeathTimer.Tick -=  DeathTimer_Tick;` note the `-=`

Comment: Where would I put it?

Comment: The DeathTimer.Tick -= DeathTimer_Tick; ? No rush, but I have two days to get this done.